# Mobile data management options disabled

Tags: samsung, settings

I have a pair of unlocked Samsung A10s. In both cases when I go to settings to manage mobile data usage ( set the billing cycle, set warnings etc.) The 'Billing cycle and data warnings' option is greyed out and doesn't respond when tapped.

What could have caused this and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 6):

Ok, this is embarrassing but I'll self answer in case anyone else falls into this.

The billing cycle and warning options are disabled if mobile data is turned off. If you turn it on they become enabled again.